# two interrelated dropdown list in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have 2 drop-down list, first drop-down list will be populated statically and its value won't change

```
<select name="first_dropdown"  id="first_dropdown" class="first_dropdown">  
  <option value="facility">facility</option>
  <option value="course">course</option>
  <option value="course">treatment</option>
</select>
```

Now i have 3 tables
    1)facility_for_office
    2)course_for_office
    3)treatment_for_office

Facility_for_office

```
id  officefacilityid  officeid
1        F1             O1
2        F2             O2
```

course_for_office

```
id  officecourseid  officeid
1      C1             O2
2      C2             O3
```

treatment_for_office

```
 id  officetreatmentid  officeid
    1       T1              O1
    2       T2              O3
```

I want that if the user selects facility from first drop-down then, the second drop-down list should display list of facility_for_office table and if he selects course then data of course_for_office should get displayed and if treatment is selected the second drop-down list should display data from treatment_for_office table, and if nothing is selected, the second drop-down list should be disabled. i tried finding jquery for it, but wasn't able to find any proper one. can anyone please tell me how it can be done

Comment: i don't see your second dropdown. and what are these tables `db` tables or `html` table elements?

Comment: @Jai these are db tables and i am not able to create the second dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax for getting the desired result. You need to get the value of the 1st drop-down using js & then use Ajax to submit the values into PHP page or function, whose response will be the the desired select box with values in json format. This on success will be used to replace the  div, where we need to show the select box.

```
 $(document).on('click','#edit_memberships',function() {

        var data = $('#first_dropdown').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/your controller/ Page location",
            type: "post",
            data:data,
            success: function(response){
                if(response.status=='success'){
                        $('#ajax_div').html(data.data.html);
                }
            }
        }); 
});
```

In the above code `#ajax_div` is the id of the div where we need the select box.

in the above code, the value of your current select-box is passed as data and you will be able to receive this as `$_POST['data']`; Once you get this value in PHP, you can use a simple if loop to select which table you want to use

```
if($_Post['data']=='facility'){ 
fetch data from Facility_for_office 
} elseif($_POST['data']=='course'){
 fetch data from course_for_office
}else{
fetch data from treatment_for_office
}
```

the create the select & do `Json Encode` the value & return it back to your function. Thats all you have to do to get the result you are looking for.